# How to add nofollow to the_post_navigation?

Tags: navigation

I tried to edit original `the_post_navigation`, inside the loop, so I could get the `rel="nofollow"` inside of it

```
the_post_navigation( array(
        'mid_size' => 3,
        'next_text' => __( 'Next frase', 'textdomain' ),
) );
```

I also tried to use a customized one, but that does not work.

```
<div class="next-timeline">
   <?php next_post_link( '%link', __( 'Próxima frase', 'adoro-frases-final' ) ); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?></a>
</div>
```

I also inserted a script to the footer, so it could insert what I want into the link, but it creates another `div.a` instead.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('div.next-timeline > a#lnk-nflw').attr('rel','nofollow')
    });
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you like these links to be "nofollow"? Their main reason in there is to be followed...

Comment: It is this project necessity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option I see is using [`{$adjacent}_post_link` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/adjacent_post_link/) and replacing the fragment of final link or prepare the link yourself from scratch.

**Replace:**

```
add_filter( 'next_post_link', 'se334246_nofollow_link', 20, 5);
add_filter( 'previous_post_link', 'se334246_nofollow_link', 20, 5);

function se334246_nofollow_link( $output, $format, $link, $post, $adjacent )
{
    $search = sprintf('rel="%s"', $adjacent);
    $output = str_replace($search, 'rel="nofollow"', $output);
    return $output;
}
```

**From scratch:**

```
add_filter( 'next_post_link', 'se334246_nofollow_link', 20, 5);
add_filter( 'previous_post_link', 'se334246_nofollow_link', 20, 5);

function se334246_nofollow_link( $output, $format, $link, $post, $adjacent )
{
    if ( !$post )
        return $output;

    $title = $post->post_title;
    $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $title, $post->ID );
    $permalink = get_permalink( $post );

    $inlink = str_replace( '%title', $title, $link );
    $inlink = str_replace( '%date', '', $inlink );

    $inlink = '<a href="' . $permalink . '" rel="nofollow">' . $inlink . '</a>';
    $output = str_replace( '%link', $inlink, $format );

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Works great!
Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the markup using the `navigation_markup_template` filter.

Just make sure the second argument passed, `$class`, is `'post-navigation'` as the `_navigation_markup()` function (which generates the html) is used by 5 functions in total, each passing a different class.